# How to update the list in a Search View

Tags: android, searchview

I have an issue , when i search an item in a search view then i am able to search the item(Object) but when i clear the text (say cancel the search,when no text is there) the list is showing the same object which i searched before , not showing all the object after the cancel.

I tried :

Adapter Class:

```
public void animateTo(List<OrderPogo> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);

    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<OrderPogo> newModels) {

        for (int i = items.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final OrderPogo model = items.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<OrderPogo> newModels) {

        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final OrderPogo model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!items.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<OrderPogo> newModels) {

        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final OrderPogo model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = items.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    public OrderPogo removeItem(int position) {
        final OrderPogo model = items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, OrderPogo model) {
        items.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final OrderPogo model = items.remove(fromPosition);
        items.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    public class CustomFilter extends Filter {
        ArrayList<OrderPogo> arrayList;
        MaterialRecylerAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<OrderPogo> filterArrayList;

        public CustomFilter(ArrayList<OrderPogo> arrayList, MaterialRecylerAdapter adapter) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if(filterArrayList!=null && filterArrayList.size()>0){
                Log.e("filterArrayList",""+filterArrayList.size());
             //   filterArrayList.addAll(arrayList);
            }


            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                    if(arrayList.get(i).getId().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }else if(arrayList.get(i).getLoadingLocation().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }else if(arrayList.get(i).getUnloadingLocation().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }else if(arrayList.get(i).getTruckNumberLrNmbr().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }else if(arrayList.get(i).getDistance().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }else if(arrayList.get(i).getDate().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }

                }
                filterResults.values = filterArrayList;
                filterResults.count = filterArrayList.size();


            }else{
                filterResults.values = items;
                filterResults.count = items.size();
              //  filterArrayList.addAll(arrayList);
//                filterResults.count= arrayList.size();
//                filterResults.values=arrayList;
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //Here i want the arraylist from the recylerview without making the arraylist static

            items= (List<OrderPogo>) results.values;
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Fragment Class Containing SearchView:

```
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                    try{
                        materialRecylerAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
                        Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange Empty String");
//                        placesListView.clearTextFilter();
//                        materialRecylerAdapter = new MaterialRecylerAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<OrderPogo>) myOrderArrayList,nextFragmentFlag,"default");
//                        materialRecylerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      //  materialRecylerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }

                }else{
                   // materialRecylerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                    final List<OrderPogo> filteredModelList = filter(myOrderArrayList, newText);
                    materialRecylerAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Filter Method in Fragment:

```
private List<OrderPogo> filter(List<OrderPogo> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<OrderPogo> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OrderPogo model : models) {
            final String text = model.getId().toLowerCase();
            final String text1 = model.getLoadingLocation().toLowerCase();
            final String text2 = model.getUnloadingLocation().toLowerCase();
            final String text3= model.getDistance().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }else if(text1.contains(query)){
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }else if(text2.contains(query)){
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }else if(text3.contains(query)){
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a check for the empty field in the search bar. When the query is empty then add all the elements back in the list and notify for the data set change.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            initList(); //reset data at the start
            if (newText.equals(""))
                initList(); //reset data when there is no query
            ...
```

The `initList` method will initialize all the list items and the adapter is linked to it. Do the `notifyDataSetChanged` at the end of the `onQueryTextChange` method to notify the adapter about the changed data set after each and every change in the search query.

Comment: how to do that ??

Comment: i had check the query is empty or not in onQueryTextChange ,but can't able to know ,how to add it again if text is empty

Comment: @PavneetSingh , yes but i can't able to conclude when text is empty then why it's showing the previous searched item only .

Comment: When newText is empty, then do sort of a refresh of the entire list. In your case, when the newText is empty, the list is not getting updated and it is showing the previously filtered list.

Comment: yes i have done like that only ..materialRecylerAdapter = new MaterialRecylerAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<OrderPogo>) myOrderArrayList,nextFragmentFlag,"default");
//                        materialRecylerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @BarnaliBhattacharjee inside your if you just need to use your original list with adapter and use notifydataset change

Comment: i put the above code in onQueryTextChange , passing the list again , but still it showing the same rsult

Comment: @PavneetSingh I tried that code , i mentioned in the comment above , but still same problem

Comment: @BarnaliBhattacharjee you are creating new adapter ,instead you just need have all the elements in the list used by adapter and notify it

Comment: @PavneetSingh Let me try

Comment: Create a new list with all elements in it and use the adapter to notify the changed data set in it.

Comment: @AlphaQ i had done it , but the previous item is coming two three times , i am updating the code

Comment: I have added a simple version of the code. That should do it. Do upvote the answer. (: